# transfer files from ssh server directly to client

Tags: python, http, ssh, web, scp

i have a ssh server which is use to store my files online. i need to make those file available for download easily so i am using paramiko library to connect to the ssh server (from my python script), it then lists files and displays on the webpage. the problem is that i dont want to download the files to the web server's disk (dont have enough space) then send them to the clients , instead do something like read the file and spit it like it can be done in php.

something like this in python

```
<?php
// your file to upload
$file = '2007_SalaryReport.pdf';
header("Expires: 0");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
// tell file size
header('Content-length: '.filesize($file));
// set file name
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
readfile($file);
// Exit script. So that no useless data is output-ed.
exit;
?>
```

Comment: the answer depends on the web framework you use. Python has several different web framkeworks with differen APIs.

Comment: i am currently trying plain cgi script but am open to webapp2 ,web.py and django..

Answer (score 1):

Not a programmer's answer: instead of paramiko, mount the directory with documents with `sshfs` and serve the documents as if they were on the local file system

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html

Comment: i am not root on the web server so cant install software ( free account )

Answer (score 0):

A cgi script generates output on `stdout` which is delivered to the webserver. The output starts with header lines, one blank line (as a separator) and then the content.

So you have to change the `header()` calls to `print` statements. And `readfile($file)` should be replaced by

```
 print
 print open("2007_SalaryReport.pdf","rb").read()
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface